Facing error with array/string serialization in anchor solana
Here is what I am trying to interact with I am getting this error
One point to mention is that when I am trying to interact with the Order if I set the tokenid type as u32 (just for testing purposes) then it works but when set as string/array then it doesn't work and throws this error when i try to interact with it, so likely the error is with token_id but i don't know why. I want to pass a token_id as a u8 array or string
  transactionLogs: [
    'Program 9VDjKtvrDTMgufDSvgYD3r4WAXJjwSDj7gaznaE9wyni invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: PlaceBuyOrder',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: InitializeAccount3',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA consumed 4214 of 379871 compute units',
    'Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA success',
    'Program log: ProgramError occurred. Error Code: BorshIoError("Not all bytes read"). Error Number: 64424509440. Error Message: IO Error: Not all bytes read.',
    'Program 9VDjKtvrDTMgufDSvgYD3r4WAXJjwSDj7gaznaE9wyni consumed 38988 of 400000 compute units',
    'Program 9VDjKtvrDTMgufDSvgYD3r4WAXJjwSDj7gaznaE9wyni failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown'
  ]


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct PlaceBuyOrder<'info> {
    /// CHECK: The user on whose behalf the order is being placed
    pub user: AccountInfo<'info>,

    /// The master authority placing the order
    #[account(mut)]
    pub master: Signer<'info>, // Payer is the master and must be mutable

    /// The user's wallet account (PDA)
    #[account(
        mut,
        seeds = [b"user-wallet", user.key().as_ref(), master.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub user_wallet: Box<Account<'info, UserWallet>>,

    /// User's USDT associated token account (owned by user)
    #[account(
        mut,
        constraint = user_wallet_usdt_account.owner == user.key(),
        constraint = user_wallet_usdt_account.delegate == Some(user_wallet.key()).into(),
    )]
    pub user_wallet_usdt_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

    /// The order account to be initialized (PDA)
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = master,
        space = 8 + Order::LEN,
        seeds = [
            b"order",
            user_wallet.action_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref(),
            user.key().as_ref(),
            master.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
        
    )]
    pub order: Account<'info, Order>,

    /// Buy order's USDT account to be initialized (PDA)
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = master,
        token::mint = usdt_mint,
        token::authority = order,
        seeds = [
            b"order-usdt-account",
            user_wallet.action_id.to_le_bytes().as_ref(),
            user.key().as_ref(),
            master.key().as_ref(),
        ],
        bump,
    )]
    pub buy_order_usdt_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,

    pub usdt_mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, TokenInterface>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,

    /// CHECK: Sysvar for instructions (used for signature verification)
    pub ix_sysvar: AccountInfo<'info>,
}

#[account]

pub struct Order {
    pub action_id: u64,
    pub amount: u64, // usd_amount for buy, ct_amount for sell
    pub expiration: u64,
    pub owner: Pubkey,
    pub token_id: [u8;80],
    pub order_type: u8, // 0 for buy, 1 for sell, 2 for withdraw
}


impl Order {
    // Calculate the total length of the Order struct (excluding discriminator)
    pub const LEN: usize = 
        8                      // action_id
        + 8                    // amount
        + 8                    // expiration
        + 32                   // owner (Pubkey)
        + 80 // token_id 
        + 1;                   // order_type
}

    pub fn place_buy_order(
        ctx: Context<PlaceBuyOrder>,
        msg: Vec<u8>,
        sig: [u8; 64],
    ) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("msg length: {}", msg.len());

        Ok(())
    }


I dont think there is anything to do with client code but still referencing this
async function placeBuyOrder(
    program: anchor.Program<PolymarketSkate>,
    master: Keypair,
    tokenId: string,
    usdAmount: number,
    user: Keypair
) {
    try {
        let userPubKey = user.publicKey;
        console.log(userPubKey.toBase58())
        // Derive the PDA for the user wallet
        const [userWalletPDA, userWalletBump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [
                Buffer.from("user-wallet"),
                userPubKey.toBuffer(),
                master.publicKey.toBuffer(),
            ],
            program.programId
        );
        const userWalletAccount = await program.account.userWallet.fetch(userWalletPDA);
        const actionId: number = parseInt(userWalletAccount.actionId!.toString());

        // Get the user's USDT ATA
        const userUsdtAta = await splToken.getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
            USDT_MINT_ADDRESS,
            userPubKey,
            undefined,
            TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
        );

        // Derive the PDA for the order account
        const [orderPDA, orderBump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [
                Buffer.from("order"),
                Buffer.from(new anchor.BN(actionId).toArray('le', 8)),
                userPubKey.toBuffer(),
                master.publicKey.toBuffer(),
            ],
            program.programId
        );

        // Derive the PDA for the buy order's USDT account
        const [buyOrderUsdtPDA, buyOrderUsdtBump] = PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
            [
                Buffer.from("order-usdt-account"),
                Buffer.from(new anchor.BN(actionId).toArray('le', 8)),
                userPubKey.toBuffer(),
                master.publicKey.toBuffer(),
            ],
            program.programId
        );

        console.log("actionId: "+actionId)
        const orderData = {
            action_id: actionId,
            amount: usdAmount,
            expiration: 0, // Replace BUY_ORDER_EXPIRATION with your value
            owner: userPubKey.toBuffer(),
            token_id: Buffer.from("00021742633143463906290569050155826241533067272736897614950488156847949938836455",'utf-8'),
            order_type: 0,
        };

        console.log({
            user: userPubKey.toBase58(),
            master: master.publicKey.toBase58(),
            userWallet: userWalletPDA.toBase58(),
            userWalletUsdtAccount: userUsdtAta.toBase58(), // Use the user's USDT ATA
            order: orderPDA.toBase58(),
            buyOrderUsdtAccount: buyOrderUsdtPDA.toBase58(),
            usdtMint: USDT_MINT_ADDRESS.toBase58(), 
            tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID.toBase58(),
            systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId.toBase58(),
            ixSysvar: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_INSTRUCTIONS_PUBKEY.toBase58(),
        })

        // Create an instance of the Order class
        const orderInstance = new Order(orderData);

        // Serialize the Order object using borsh
        const message = borsh.serialize(OrderSchema, orderInstance);
        console.log(message.length)
        // console.log(messageBuffer)
        // Sign the message with the user's private key
        const signature = nacl.sign.detached(message, user.secretKey);

        const ed25519Instruction = Ed25519Program.createInstructionWithPublicKey({
            publicKey: userPubKey.toBytes(),
            message,
            signature,
        });

        const transaction = new Transaction();

        // Add the Ed25519 signature verification instruction first
        transaction.add(ed25519Instruction);
        // Initialize the buy order
        const ix = await program.methods
            .placeBuyOrder(Buffer.from(message), Array.from(signature))
            .accounts({
                user: userPubKey,
                master: master.publicKey,
                userWallet: userWalletPDA,
                userWalletUsdtAccount: userUsdtAta, // Use the user's USDT ATA
                order: orderPDA,
                buyOrderUsdtAccount: buyOrderUsdtPDA,
                usdtMint: USDT_MINT_ADDRESS, 
                tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
                systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
                ixSysvar: anchor.web3.SYSVAR_INSTRUCTIONS_PUBKEY,
            })
            .signers([master])
            .instruction();

        transaction.add(ix);


        const provider = program.provider;
        transaction.feePayer = master.publicKey;
        const { blockhash } = await provider.connection.getLatestBlockhash();
        transaction.recentBlockhash = blockhash;

        // Sign the transaction with the master keypair
        transaction.sign(master);

        // Send the transaction
        const txid = await provider.connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize(), {
            skipPreflight: false,
            preflightCommitment: 'confirmed',
        });

        console.log(`Buy order placed successfully. Transaction ID: ${txid}`);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error placing buy order:", error);
    }
}

class Order {
    action_id: anchor.BN;
    amount: anchor.BN;
    expiration: anchor.BN;
    owner: Uint8Array;
    token_id: Uint8Array;
    order_type: number;

    constructor(fields: {
        action_id: number | anchor.BN;
        amount: number | anchor.BN;
        expiration: number | anchor.BN;
        owner: Uint8Array | PublicKey;
        token_id: Uint8Array;
        order_type: number | anchor.BN;
    }) {
        this.action_id = new anchor.BN(fields.action_id);
        this.amount = new anchor.BN(fields.amount);
        this.expiration = new anchor.BN(fields.expiration);
        this.owner = fields.owner instanceof PublicKey ? fields.owner.toBytes() : fields.owner;
        this.token_id = fields.token_id;
        this.order_type = Number(fields.order_type);
    }
}

// Updated schema to match Rust struct exactly
const OrderSchema: borsh.Schema = {
    struct: {
        action_id: 'u64',
        amount: 'u64',
        expiration: 'u64',
        owner: { array: { type: 'u8', len: 32 } },
        token_id: { array: { type: 'u8', len: 80 } },
        order_type: 'u8',
    }
};


Your Order struct in Rust has token_id defined as [u8; 80], meaning it expects a 80-byte array. If the serialized data for token_id doesn't match this length, Borsh will throw an error since it expects exactly 80 bytes. When you tested with u32, the struct size changed, likely allowing serialization to work but not as intended.
Fix Suggestion
Check that token_id in orderData is indeed 80 bytes when you’re constructing it in your JavaScript client. You’re currently using:
javascript
token_id: Buffer.from("00021742633143463906290569050155826241533067272736897614950488156847949938836455",'utf-8')

This encoding might not yield an 80-byte buffer. For testing, try manually setting an 80-byte buffer like:
javascript
token_id: Buffer.from("0".repeat(80)), // or create an actual 80-byte array with relevant values

